# JavaScript setTimeout not calling a function is some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple chrome extension and have trouble using setTimout function. My js script looks like this:

```
console.log('Page loaded!');
setTimeout(execExtention,500);
function execExtention(){
    console.log('Exec script after delay');
    ...
}
```

Once I open the web page, in console I get messages "Page loaded!" and "Exec script after delay" -all good, but once I press SAVE button (it makes AJAX call and reloads iframe) on the page, I get only "Page loaded!"and for some reason setTimeout does not execute execExtention. If I change to "setTimeout(execExtention(),500)", then I get both messages, but second one without any delay (like it should because of "()"). Could someone please explain what could cause this issue to happen, why function is not executed in setTimeout?
The reason I am trying to use setTimeout is because I did not find a working solution to execute script once all frames are loaded or some frames are re-loaded. $(document).ready(...), $(window).on('load'...) did not seem work for me.

Comment: well adding the () executes the function and assign what it returns to be called by the timeout. Why does it not work, no clue without seeing an example that shows the issue.

Comment: Are you running this in the main page or the iframe?

Comment: The above script runs from the extension, it is added in my.js and  referenced in manifest.json file. Besides my.js I also have reference to jquery.js, nothing else. I cannot show the real example, as the page I am trying to use this extension requires authorization.